# 9 Speed Shimano cassette on 10+ speed hub

Tags: cassette, wheels

I've got a 2010 Specialized Tricross with a mostly original drivetrain and wheels. Notably for this question:

```
Front derailleur: Shimano Tiagra  
Rear derailleur: Shimano Deore LX
Chainset: Shimano Tiagra 50 x 39 x 30T
Wheelset: AlexRims Ace 19, with no-name (unmarked) hubs
Cassette: Shimano Sora HG50 9 Speed 12-25t (replaced stock Shimano HG-50, 9-speed, 11-32t)
Cassette Lockring: Shimano Hyperglide CS-HG50-9
```

Based on a [previous question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77114/questions-about-cracks-in-my-rim), my rims are at the end of their life, and the hubs and spokes are probably not worth salvaging for a rebuild. So I'm exploring options for replacement wheels. I don't want to change the drivetrain if I can avoid that since I don't think the bike's worth that much of an upgrade.

Looking around online, I see some wheels specify, for the rear wheel, Shimano 10/11 speed compatibility, without specifying 9 speed compatibility. I also see mixed feedback on other forums as to whether 9 speed Shimano cassettes can go on 10/11 speed hubs. Most [existing questions](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=9%20speed%20cassette%20on%2010%20speed%20hub) on this site are asking the reverse, i.e. if you can put a 10+ speed casette on 9 speed wheel.

So my questions are:

1. If I'm looking at a set of wheels that says it's 10/11 speed Shimano compatible, is it safe to assume I'd be able to put my 9 speed cassette on it?
2. For a couple of specific examples, should I expect a [Campagnolo Calima C17](https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/campagnolo-calima-c17-road-wheelset/rp-prod170199) (Shimano version) or [Vision Team 30](https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/vision-team-30-clincher-road-wheelset/rp-prod137637) to accept my existing 9 speed cassette? Both are 700c rim brake road wheelsets that specify 10/11 speed compatibility.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

9 speed cassette is as wide as 10 speed cassette for Shimano parts. Thus, 10 speed compatible is 9 speed compatible, and is 8 speed compatible too (and 7 speed compatible with a large spacer).

However, if the 11 speed compatibility refers to Shimano 11-speed road, then in that case you need 1.85mm spacer to install 11 speed MTB, or 8-10 speed cassettes.

The Campagnolo wheelset has a horrible spoking pattern, don't choose it, it will be a nightmare to maintain and won't withstand any significant weight.

The Vision Team 30 wheelset has too few spokes. It thus won't withstand any significant weight.

Instead, I recommend you finding a quality 36-spoke rim with double eyelets such as DT Swiss TK 540. Pair it with Shimano cup and cone hubs, and install triple butted 2.34mm/1.8mm/2.0mm spokes from a reputable manufacturer such as DT Swiss. If you can't build the wheels on your own, it'll be a very good investment to purchase the wheelbuilding from a professional wheelbuilder. The price won't exceed that of ["boutique"](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_bo-z.html#boutique) wheels but the durability will be at least several hundred times more miles if you put any significant weight on the wheels.

Comment: A 36 spoke wheel would be completely overkill for this type of bike, unless the rider weighs >100kg or rides with a lot of luggage. All the reviews I can find mention how sturdy and strong the Campa C17 are (for a road bike wheelset).

Comment: To add to Michael's comment, the AlexRims Ace19s that came on the bike were, AFAIK, pretty low end 32-spoke wheels, and I got ~18,000km out of those.

Comment: The Campagnolo wheels are beautiful and though some instances don't like them. And they are indestructible, even though they have 27 / 18 spokes only. The rims have no internal spoke holes that can damage your tubes no matter the state of the rim-tape.