# My bike has a 10 speed cassette. MTX hub motor takes 9 speed cassette can I remove last cog of my cassette without issues?

Tags: mountain-bike, gears, cassette, compatibility, electric-bike

I need some advice. I have a Giant Anthem 2012 dual suspension bike. And want to put a 1500 watt 26" MTX cassette type rear hub motor onto it. I believe the MTX wheel can take up to a 9-speed cassette. Not sure if it can take anymore; if anyone does, can you please let me know as I have a 10-speed cassette and want to transfer this onto the MTX hub motor wheel? If it can't take my 10-speed cassette, What would happen if it couldn't take 10 speed cogs and I had to take one of the cogs away to make it a 9-speed cog? Would this create any complications with my gears? And if I took, let's say, the last big cog away from the 10-speed cog to make it a 9, would that just mean I couldn't use the last gear? Sorry for so many questions. I am new to all this and don't know a lot about bikes. That is why I joined up here—to learn from people who are in the know. Thanks

Comment: What brand is the cassette and the derailleur? What exact type of hub motor? You cannot just create a 9-speed cassette by removing one cog. And even just installing a 9-speed cassette on a bike with 10-speed shifter is not  something that is supposed to work. The number of gears your bike is trying to use is determined by the shifter. Based on how much cable the shifter pulls that is translated by the derailleur to the movement between the cogs by a certain distance. The whole complex must be compatible.

Comment: The cassette and the derailleur is a Shimano Dyna sys and the hub motor can be seen on this website :

https://www.ebikemasters.uk/product-page/29-1500w-mtx-rear-wheel-motor-kit

Comment: OK, it is something completely different to what I thought it is.

Comment: Personally, I'd say that a 1,500W motor nudges your ebike from the realm of pedal assist into the realm of motorbikes...

Comment: Hey Chris, where did you get the information about the compatibility of up to a 9-speed cassette for the hub motor? I tried to look a bit and could not find any meaningful documentation regarding that.

Comment: I'd suggest asking the vendor of the motor if your cassette will fit. And while you're at it you may want to check if that beast is still street legal after you built it.

Answer (score 1):

Cassette, derailleur, shifter lever, chain wheel and even chain must all be compatible to work together. There are some other compatible combinations than just all the number of gears but at least [read this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/86396/rear-wheel-cassette-hub-and-speed-set-compatibility-question).

Assuming you do not change the gear ratio of the previous 9 gears, it should be no difference for the hub and its controller. I am less sure if it will work well with the 10th gear or if the gear ratios are different but for some simpler programmed controller it may. Or put two identical sprockets.